# Nestjs apply function to each controller function/routes after validation has done

Tags: javascript, api, guard, nestjs

my controller:

```
    @Post('route1')
    @HttpCode(202)
    fun1(@Body() req: reqModel) {
        this.service1.findAll()  
        //do smth
        return true;
    }

    @Post('route2')
    @HttpCode(202)
    fun2(@Body() req: reqModel) {
        this.service1.findAll()  
        //do smth
        return true;
    }
```

I am trying to achieve the following mechanism:

1- validation has passed because I have model and class-validator in the models

2- now I want to call a service to get some data in each function in this controller 
this service check smth and then throw an exception or return true

I tried to use Guard `@UseGuards(guradclass)` but the guards works before the class validator

how can I achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution order is the following if that can help you

•   Middleware
•   Guards
•   Interceptors (before the stream is manipulated)
•   Pipes
•   Interceptors (after the stream is manipulated)
•   Exception filters (if any exception is caught)